# how to patchvalue in edit page of nested array in angular8?

Tags: angular8

html code:(Here i added the html code to iterate the nested array which i want to get the value in edit page ) `getMaterialListArray(i)` => this method should iterate the array values when i click the select+ button.

```
 <p>Sub Recipes</p>
             <div formArrayName="recipeArray" *ngFor="let item of recipeArray.controls; let i = index;">
                 <div [formGroupName]="i" class="add-div" >
                      <mat-accordion>
                        <mat-expansion-panel>
                            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                                <mat-panel-title>
                                        Sub Recipe{{i+1}}
                                </mat-panel-title>                   
                            </mat-expansion-panel-header>

                                    <div class="add-div">
                                        Material
                            <mat-list role="list"  formcontrolName="material">
                                <mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let data of getMaterialListArray(i)">
                                    <div class="file-name">
                                        <span>{{data.title}}</span> 
                                        <div>{{item.wt_in_kgs_per_unit}}{{item.uom}}</div>
                                         <div class="btn-custom" (click)="deleteMaterial(data, i)">Delete</div>
                                    </div>
                                </mat-list-item>                   
                            </mat-list>
                        </div>
                       <div class="btn-custom" (click)="addMaterial(i)">select+</div>
                       <br><br>
                       <div class="add-div">
                           otherFormulation
                            <mat-list role="list">
                                    <mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let form of getFormulationListArray(i)">
                                        <div class="file-name">
                                            <span>{{form.title}}</span> 
                                            <div>{{form.batch_qty}}{{form.unit_type}} </div>
                                            <div class="btn-custom"(click)="deleteOtherFormulation(form, i)">Delete</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </mat-list-item>                   
                                </mat-list>
                            </div>

                            <div class="btn-custom" (click)="addOtherFormulation(i)">select+</div>
                      </mat-expansion-panel>
                 </mat-accordion>
             </div>
        </div>
```

component.ts:(commented lines are gives an error. please give me an solution to patch value from nested array) the pattern of an array)

```
List : [] = array[{
internalCode:Fo-3684,
title:biscuit,
refer_subrecipe:[{
        material_id:[{ title:biscuit,
                     internalCode:Fo-3434
},
{
 title:cake,
 internalCode:Fo-3488
}]

}],
Refer_packaging:[{
 material_id:[{
           title:candywrapper,
            uom:10kg
},
{
           title:candypack,
            uom:20kg
}] 
}]  like this....
  this.formulationForm.patchValue({internalCode : result.internalCode,
                                           myCode:result.myCode,
                                           title : result.title,
                                           unitsOfMeasurement:result.unit_type,
                                           batchQuantity:result.batch_qty,
                                           productType:result.product_type,
                                          //  recipeArray: {
                                          //    material:result.Refer_SubRecipe.material_id.title,
                                          //   otherformulations:result.Refer_SubRecipe.material_id.title
                                          // },
                                          //   packageArray:{
                                          //     packMaterial:result.Refer_Packaging.material_id.title,
                                          //     UOM:result.Refer_Packaging.material_id.uom,
                                          //     weight:result.Refer_Packaging.material_id.wt_in_kgs_per_unit,
                                          //     Quantity:result.Refer_Packaging.material_id.quantity
                                          //   },
                                           allergen:this.alergenList,
                                           shelf_life:this.alergenList,
                                           operational_instruction:result.ops_instructions,
                                           version_no:result.version,
                                           version_date:result.version_date,
                                           approved_by:result.approved_by,
                                           remarks: result.remarks });
   }
    })
    this.recipeArray = this.formulationForm.get('recipeArray') as FormArray;

    this.packageArray = this.formulationForm.get('packageArray') as FormArray;

  }
```